# Audacity: How to smooth out equalization transitions

Tags: audacity, equalization, equalizer

So, on one section of an audio file, I have a 15db 140hz boost, and and in the next, I have a 12db 140hz boost. How would I smoothly transition these without it sounding odd, and suddenly changing. This is simply an example scenario, so telling me how to do this between other transitions as well would really help. Thanks.

---

Note: *So, this is my first question in the sound stack exchange, and I'm not all that great with music production. The most musical talent I have is playing french horn and trumpet, and noobishness should be expected.*

Comment: I actually wrote you an answer on this, but had to delete it - I had actually forgotten how hard something like this is to do in Audacity. It's a nightmare. It should be really simple, but it isn't. If you can find something else to use - maybe the free version of Protools - anything else - I am sure you will find it much easier.

Comment: Like Mark said, this will be pretty devilishly hard in Audacity, but in any DAW that supports automation, you can just automate the gain on that EQ band from 15dB to 12dB with a smooth curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to consider is duplicating your track(s), either entirely or in sections, and applying various EQs or other parameters to different track sets. You can then use the volume envelope tool to control which configuration is 'present', essentially crossfading between profiles at whatever rate suits you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific feature in audacity that would allow this, and the best way to do this it to either increase or decrease the decibel level in small increments.